# first jquery project - using handlers in functions to modularize them

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my javascript books I read that creating many separate "modules" is a good way to go. Yet when I apply this philosophy to my first jQuery project, my functions are getting called multiple times for no apparent reason.

My plan was:

Have one function to handle the number entry from the web page (click).

Have a second function (also shown here) to handle input verification.

Have a third function (not shown) to handle the number processing only if module 2 finds the number to be valid.

If either function 2 or 3 fails the number, they call `enterNumber()` once again, which then waits for the user to 'click' in a new number.

What happens instead is, calling `enterNumber()` seems to be 'clicking' the `$('#button)` without the user doing anything at all.

First of all, is this a legitimate treatment of the click handler? It's generating way too many loops the way it's written now.

```
var enterNumber = function () {
        $('#button').click(function(){
            guess = $('#input').val();
            $('#input').val("").focus();
            verifyNumbers(guess);
        });

        $('#input').keyup(function(event){
            if (event.keyCode == 13){
                $('#button').click();
            }
        });
};

var verifyNumbers = function(x) {
    if (isNaN(x))
    {
        $("#display").html("You must type in numbers, not letters or spaces");
        $('#input').val("").focus();
        enterNumber();
    }
    else if (x > 100)
    {
        $("#display").html("You must type in numbers below 100");
        $('#input').val("").focus();
        enterNumber();
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("number is legit");
        //compareNumbers(x);
    }
};

enterNumber();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of enterNumber only need to be called on page load.  You are binding jQuery events.  If you call enterNumber more than once, you then have more than one handler on that event (that does the same thing, hence multiple calls).  Solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    enterNumber();
}
```

What this does it bind the events on page load.  Once they are bound, you should not bind them again.

You then remove the enterNumber calls in your other two functions, since the handlers are already listening for click and keyup events -- which will call verifyNumbers once the event is fired off.

Comment: multiple handlers. It's obvious now. Thanks!